# Reverse HTML code to string?

Tags: html, string, character-encoding, html-escape-characters

I have this div:

```
<div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_raw_js below_header_adsense" >
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">

        </div>
    </div>
```

And I want to reverse it to a string. So I can replaced the div with my div in php. But how can I find out, where a `\t`, a `\n` or a  (space) is hidding?

Kind reagards

Answer (score 0):

HTML ignores white space. I haven't worked with PHP so I'm not 100% but I'd first try to treat it like a normal string if not I know other languages support a split with multiple delimiters ("/n/t") I'd also try that